# Why does a client TCP connection onto a REDIS server opens 2 ports on the client?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pyabc

I am using the REDIS server from [pyABC](https://github.com/ICB-DCM/pyABC) package) with specific workloads (reads/writes in queue) distributed across several machines.
I notice that for each process launched on a host machine, 2 connections are established with the server, from 2 different ports (on the client side) towards a single port (6379) on the server side. Each of those two connections are initiated from the same process but have different inodes. From my assessment of the library's code, the process only opens one socket.

I am wondering why it is that way rather than opening a single port, and if it is related to this matter: https://blog.flipkart.tech/linux-tcp-so-reuseport-usage-and-implementation-6bfbf642885a

Another possibility is that the client itself runs a small server instance (opening a new port) that connects/listens to the main server on port 6379 (as suggested in [Java TCP Connection From Server through Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513319/java-tcp-connection-from-server-through-client)). However, that sounds overly complicated and I doubt that it is the case here.

I need to explain to my IT department what ports my workers/server open/close and why, in order to be allowed to run the service. I can’t really figure out why it opens 2 ports rather than 1.

Thanks for any insight!

ps: for checking open ports, I run `lsof -i` on the client to see the established connections with the server. I notice 2 connections for each running process with 2 different inodes (DEVICES field).